# Python with Handheld Barcode Scanner and Keyboard Input

Tags: python, pygame, barcode-scanner, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on a project that uses a physical barcode scanner.  My code will wait for a scan input for the scanner to proceed and process the barcode.  I would also like the use of a keyboard (eventually touch input but not important now) to trigger events.  I'm using evdev for the input device.  So this is my normal function that works fine:

```
def getScan(): #Captures scan from barcode reader
    devices = [InputDevice(path) for path in list_devices()]
    matching_objs = [device for device in devices if "1.1" in device.phys]
    if matching_objs:
        for device in matching_objs:
            dev = InputDevice(device.path)
    else:
        proScan('close')
    dev.grab()
    x = ''
    caps = False
    print('Waiting For Scan')
    for event in dev.read_loop():
        if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
            data = categorize(event)
            if data.scancode == 42:
                if data.keystate == 1:
                    caps = True
                if data.keystate == 0:
                    caps = False

            if data.keystate == 1:
                if caps:
                    key_lookup = u'{}'.format(capscodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  
                else:
                    key_lookup = u'{}'.format(scancodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  

                if (data.scancode != 42) and (data.scancode != 28):
                    x += key_lookup

                if(data.scancode == 28):
                    print(x)
                    return(x)
```

I would like to merge it somehow with this. This is an alternate which I also have working:

```
def getScan1(): #Test bench
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    return'stage'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    return'ok'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    return'cancel'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    return'close'
```

I don't know how to get them both working at the same time.

I tried putting both pieces of code in one function

Comment: lol I want to see this game rn

Comment: I'd suggest you specify which library you're using for the InputDecvice. The best would be if that library had a function for polling events non-blocking, or could register callbacks.

Comment: I'm using evdev for the InputDevice